# Is a question about web hosts appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Specifically asking for recommendations?  I realize this is somewhat subjective, but I believe it could also be fairly objective.  For instance, I recently discovered that my webhost (1and1) does not allow setting an SPF record, so I am unable to fix an issue with email from my domain being flagged as spam in some cases.  A question about which hosting service to use could ask for specific technical features/options to backup the recommendation.

Answer (score 8):

I definitely think that is an appropriate question here. I've already asked a similar question.

Comment: +1 as long as specific technical requirements are stated.  I would hate to see it get into a "this one is better" argument.

Comment: So far the atmosphere on this beta has been very good, unlike the web applications beta site, so it's hard to imagine a shouting match like that here. Let's hope this site maintains its quality as the audience broadens.

Comment: I'd agree with @JasonBirch - A question like 'what is the best host for PHP/MySQL?' is wayyyy too broad. A question like "I need a host that lets me update my DNS records via an API" is better.

Answer (score 4):

If you have questions about hosting, with regards to particular technical details, then they would certainly be on a site run by and for webmasters. Hosting is a webmaster concern, after all.

Answer (score 3):

If they don't [lead to answers like this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company/328#328), or other situations where people promote themselves or use paid affiliate links.

Again, this can't become a discussion forum.

Comment: I agree, but it's ok, it was made Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019, it's [considered off-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a appropriate also a generic question like:

> "Please reccomend a webhosting you used and you are happy with!"

as long as it's made Community Wiki.

I would be very happy to read raccomandations about webhosting services. I know that a good stackexchange reputation in webmaster does not necessarly mean also that user is trustworthy in being fear when suggest a webhosting (I mean he could work for a webhosting company and obviously suggest his one), but even on a forum or a blog or Facebook suggestions could come from untrustworthy people, one strong plus of stackexcahnge is the reputation.

Maybe it's a mistake thinking like me, but I would be more prone to follow a webhosting service suggested on webmasteR by a user with hight reputation rather than one suggested by a user with low rep or a new user.

Moreover one big advantage is that if I follow his reccomandation and I'm happy with the hosting service I could +1 the reccomandation, (I could also +1 it because I'm using that hoster too since quite a time and I already know it) and when unhappy, come back and -1 it adding also a comment explaining the reason.

**I think webhosting is extremely related with webmaster**.

**You can be great in doing websites, but if your hosting goes down, your customer will complain with YOU and think YOU are untrustworthy.**

Comment: I disagree, there is no definitive answer on such a question. From the [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): "avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”" Offers can be asked on http://www.webhostingtalk.com/hostquote.php, which is more suitable for such requests.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: in-fact I saied "as long as it's made Community Wiki." Don't you think I could also say: "so why are you reccomending webhostingtalk, do you maybe have some affiliations or interest in that forum?!" Moreover the link you suggest seems to be related to something of quite old, look at the boxes "How much monthly transfer/storage space will you need?" The select lists show values that were common 5 years ago, but now stroage space is so cheap and even bandwidth is sold in huge quantities.

Comment: I'm not affiated with http://webhostingtalk.com in any way. [A Community Wiki](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) should not be abused for such questions which are more like discussions in which an upvote means "I like it" and a downvote "I dislike it". From the [CW privilege description](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki): "Community wiki posts have been donated to the community in hopes that others will edit them to keep them up to date, to add useful information, and generally improve their quality."

Comment: webhostingtalk.com was just an example which I know of, IMO this Q&A site is not suitable for offer requests and such.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: "Community wiki posts have been donated to the community in hopes that others will edit them to keep them up to date" well seeing many plus one on a webhoster suggested by a user is a big gift to a webmasters community! There is no definitive answer also to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs/3637493#3637493 but it's a great question as long as it's community wiki.