# Are Host Recommendation Questions - On Topic?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

I've seen the post [Host Recommendation Questions - On Topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/host-recommendation-questions-on-topic), which seems to indicate that hosting recommendations are on topic, but I can't tell if that is the case.

The highest voted answer says that they are ok, but there is a post from a moderator saying that they are not ok, so...

Are questions that involve hosting recommendations accepted on this site? Is there some documentation that indicates the "official stance" for pro webmasters that I can link to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that questions, and others, were asked, a "catch-all" question has been defined which doesn't recommend specific hosts, but tells you how to work through the process of making the choice:

[How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

That question has a link to the meta question which started it off.

You might find that if you ask a new question it will get closed down and you will be told to look at the catch-all question.