# We need to decide what we're doing with users looking for existing software

Tags: discussion, looking-for-a-script

Now that we've gotten [questions pertaining to hosting recommendations situated](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/we-need-to-decide-what-were-doing-with-web-hosting-questions) I think we need to turn our attention to users [looking for software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script).

It's clearly a popular topic here at Pro Webmasters as it is in the top 15 tags. However, these questions really tend to fall under "too localized" as each question is specifically geared towards the question-asker's needs. Not to mention it's yet another opportunity for spammers and self promoters to hawk their wares.

Should we take a similar approach to these questions as we did with hosting requests and create a CW that explains how to shop for web hosting? If so, what would the question need to contain to be useful to anyone looking for software?

Comment: Discussion continues (with live question) at [New Catch-All: “Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?”](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/685/new-catch-all-which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that unlike the looking for hosting questions these are too varied to be able to write a sensible CW question for them. If you look at the list of other tags on the right of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script you can see a wide variety.

However we could write several "how to pick *X*" questions where X is CMS, ecommerce package, shopping cart and photo gallery. They seem to be the top requests.

Comment: You echoed my thoughts about one CW to rule them all not being a realistic option. I never considered making multiple ones for each type of script, though. It may not cover every question but would cover most of them.

Comment: +1 "How to find a CMS that meets my requirements?" would be a good starting point that might mop up some of the most common script requests. Most of the other looking-for-a-script tags appear too diverse to sub-categorise, and I'm not sure there are enough requests for ecommerce packages, shopping carts, and galleries to warrant a community wiki for them yet.

Comment: As a side note, can we change the `looking-for-a-script` tag (if we're keeping those questions) to a more concise name? Something like `script-rec` for recommendations, similar to other sites.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of sites, such as [forum-software.org](http://www.forum-software.org/), that people can use to find scripts. We could create a community wiki with a list of sites like that.