# New Catch All: What Forum Software should I use?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, looking-for-a-script, catch-all

This question is now live: [What forum software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

As per [this answer](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/688/6901), here is a new catch all for people looking for a forum script:

Question:

> I have a list of features that I want for my website's forum script - where can I find a [free] script that includes all of them?

Answer:

> The [Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/688/6901) outlines the nature of acceptable questions for this site: researching available solutions and providing anecdotal advice falls outside the purpose of this StackExchange site, so this type of question would be better-suited to [chat](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/688/6901) or another discussion forum.
>
> That being said, there are a variety of free and open source content management systems, as well as licensed software and paid services, which may meet your requirements.
>
> Some of the most popular forum scripts include:
>
> - [PHPBB](http://www.phpbb.org/) (php, free and open source)
>
>   - Pros: been around for a long time, so there are lots of documentation and mods for it. Has lots of features.
>   - Cons: Installing mods is not easy
> - [Fluxbb](http://www.fluxbb.org/) (php, free and open source)
>
>   - Pros: very lightweight and simple
>   - Cons: hard to install mods, not a lot of features.
>
> All of the forum software listed above are built around the concept of mods (plugins) which extend the application's functionality - there are many mods, with new mods authored every day.
>
> Sites like [forum-software.org](http://www.forum-software.org/) can help you compare different forum software, and have forum comparison tools and in-depth reviews.
>
> If you have researched different forum software and available mods but cannot find anything that will meet your needs, you should consult a developer who can build something to your specifications either as a mod for an existing forum script or as a stand-alone application.

NOTE: This is adapted from this question: [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use/)

Is this a good question/answer? Any improvements? Should this question go live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job. Go live. We can add to it once you do.

Comment: One note: Don't forget to vote the Q and A up when you stop by!